# Solving equations in C++

Tags: c++, math, equations

I'm very new to C++ and I've been given a task to solve this quadratic equation:

> 5x2^ + 6x-1 = 0

How do I achieve this by writing C++ code?

**Edit:** Placed the code I tried using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sq, sixq, single, sum
    sq = 5 * 5;
    sixq = 6;
    single = -1 ;
    sum = sq + sixq - single;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: By writing proper C++ code, compiling it and executing the compilation result.

Comment: Could you first try to solve the mathematical part of this problem, than try to implement it in C++, and then come back when you cannot figure out how?

Comment: I've tried to figure out how and haven't achieved it. I can't implement the string values (x) next to the integers. I've tried

Comment: ***I can't implement the string values (x) next to the integers.*** Post a new question about that showing the minimal complete code that shows the problem you are having. This should be an easy one to get help with. Don't mention the math problem at all since it is irreverent to converting string to int.

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ polynomial".  This should give plenty of examples on how to represent a polynomial and evaluate it.

Comment: Use the formula you were taught at school to solve for x.

Comment: How much more general is the problem the program is supposed to solve relative to the example you gave?  If the example is the whole thing, just figure out the answer by hand and `cout` that answer.  If the program must cover whatever quadratic equation you input, just use the quadratic formula.  If the program must cover whatever polynomial you input, Newton's method isn't difficult.  If it must solve any equation at all, you aren't skilled enough to attempt that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about *evaluating* the expression, you could do something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int x;
  std::cout << "Enter value for x: ";
  std::cin >> x;
  const int x_squared = x * x;

  const int y = 5 * x_squared + 6 * x - 1;
  cout << "\nResult: " << y << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

See @Bathsheba's answer for finding the roots of the expression.

Answer (score 5):

Given `axx + bx + c = 0`, the first job is to compute `b * b - 4 * a * c`. If that is less than zero then there are no *real* roots for the quadratic. Your program should return an error at this point, unless it's equipped to deal with *complex* numbers.

Else you can compute `sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)` which we will call `D`.

Then the roots (i.e. the solutions) are `-(b + D) / (2 * a)` and `-(b - D) / (2 * a)`.

Note that you should use `double` for the computations of `D` and the roots. It's unlikely that these will evaluate to integers.